# How to avoid Heads-up notification on android Oreo and above?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-notification-bar

I want to show the notification in the background. Means, while user opening the notification screen.

But its coming on the top of my app screen. I don't want to show at the top of the my app.

I want to show only in the notification bar.

Can someone suggest, what is the property that I have to set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your activity is not full screen.

Set low priority to your notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder.setContentTitle(fileName)
                .setContentText("Notification")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

and low importance to your notification channel

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```